# WP7 - Cannot set background of button once it has been clicked

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I have this memory game app that I'm working on, trying to learn WP7. Imagine 6 uniquely colored buttons on the screen where the sequence has to be repeated by the user.

1. First pass, disable all buttons, change Button1's background
2. All buttons enabled, user clicks Button 1, game continues...
3. Second pass, disable all buttons, Button 1 and 3 are to be highlighted
4. Only Button3's background is changed (debugging shows that procedure to change Button1's background was run)

The highlighting of the buttons is simply changing to a lighter background. Whatever button is clicked, it will not be available to change the background color in subequent passes.

Style XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <!--Define the states for the common states. The states in a 
                                        VisualStateGroup are mutually exclusive to each other.-->
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <!--Define the VisualStates in this VistualStateGroup.-->
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="White" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        </Storyboard>                                        
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                <!--Define the states for the focus states. The states in a 
                                        VisualStateGroup are mutually exclusive to each other.-->
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <!--Define the VisualStates in this VistualStateGroup.-->
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <!--The parts of the button control will be defined here.-->
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Button:

```
<Button Height="121" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,61,0,0" Name="but1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="197" Background="#FF7D0000" BorderBrush="Black" Foreground="Red" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Click="but1_Click" />
```

Should I replicate a StackPanel/Rectangle to replace my button? Or is there a style or basic thing that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I changed the Pressed state of my button's style - this after having compared my style and the default style of a button. It would seem I was missing some code.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

This was a stab in the dark :)